# Can we access GCP services using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I came across [this doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) which says that Apps Script can connect to any external APIs.
I'm trying to access my Virtual Machines and maybe perform some actions (GET, DELETE etc). Can I do that using [Compute Engine APIs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1#rest-resource:-v1.instances) using Apps Script.

Thank you

It works perfectly within Google Workspace Ecosystem but not sure how to begin connecting GCP services using Apps Script.

Comment: I wrote something about AppScript and Cloud Run integration. You can reuse the same OAuth2 and scope mechanism for you sue case. https://medium.com/google-cloud/call-cloud-run-from-app-script-the-easy-way-70677086efa1

Comment: Thank you @guillaumeblaquiere. Following the blog, I keep running into this error `You cannot switch to a Cloud Platform project outside the script owner's Cloud Organization.`
I followed the workaround mentioned here https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Workspace-Developer/Error-while-attempting-to-switch-from-default-to-standard-GCP/m-p/164068 but it's not working. 
Any suggestions? thank you!

Comment: I don't know if it's an AppScript limitation (I'm not App Script expert!) or a Google Cloud organization policy. Do you know if there is organisation policies in place on your project? It sounds like DRS (Domain Restriction Sharing)